# Strapi $AND query filter returns values filtered with $OR

Tags: axios, strapi

I'd like to filter my strapi collection and get results that match all of my criteria, so a classic $AND filtering.

Here's an example on what my documents inside my "listings" collection look like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listings": [
      {
        "name": "Three bedroom Apartment for lease in Sun Ancora Residence",
        "price": 1200,
        "size": 110,
        "rooms": 3,
        "features": [
          "Library"
          "Air Conditioning",
          "Wi-fi",
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet yadda yadda",
        "price": 1200,
        "size": 110,
        "rooms": 3,
        "features": [
          "Library"
          "Tennis",
          "Playground",
          "Cable TV",
          "Wi-fi",
        ]
      },      
    }
  }
}
```

So, if I send a GET request like http://localhost:1337/listings?features_in=Library&features_in=Tennis I expect the array to be filtered with $AND but it is clearly an $OR.

The expected result would be to get only the second document of my example, instead I get both entries.

The documentation (https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/filters.html#available-operators) says:

> If you use the same operator (except for in and nin) the values will be used to build an OR query

That's what I'm doing here: `features_in=Library&features_in=Tennis`.

Anyone knows how to create a filter that works with $AND?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not exist in Strapi. Can you please check if an issue already exist on the GitHub and if not, can you please create a feature request for this need. Thank you.

The workaround here is to create a custom route/controller and make a custom database query that matches your need.

Here is the documentation to create a new endpoint: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/controllers.html#adding-endpoints

To access the data model, you will have to use strapi.models.article (For an Article model) and inside this variable, you will access to native Mongoose or Bookshelf function. So you will be able to query with an OR